# How can I make my scrollable table 100% window width?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/dqq5B/515/

```
      <div>

<style>
        <table class = "table table-hover">
            <tr>
               <th> Game ID </th>
               <th> Status </th>
               <th> Players </th>
               <th> Turn </th>
               <th> Last Turn </th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td> 1 </td>
               <td> IN PROGRESS </td>
               <td> 4/4 </td>
               <td> tedbeem </td>
               <td> 11/12/13 6:30 PM </td>

           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td> 2 </td>
               <td> RECRUITING </td>
               <td> 4/5 </td>
               <td> N/A </td>
               <td> 11/12/13 3:10 PM </td>

           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td> 13 </td>
               <td> IN PROGRESS </td>
               <td> 3/3 </td>
               <td> D-Halt-on </td>
               <td> 11/12/13 9:00 AM </td>

            </tr>
        </table>

    table tr td:last-child {
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 1px;

    }

    table {

         display: block;
            overflow-x: auto;
            width:100%;
    }

    div{margin:0 auto; width:100%}

</style>
```

Comment: Is it the table you want 100%?  If so, display it as a table -- table { 
     display: table;
        overflow-x: auto;
        width:100%;
}

Comment: @cmerriman yes this is working!

Comment: Remove display: block from the table css

Comment: @JamesKing This is working too!

Comment: @JamesKing No sorry, I was wrong. Then it is not scrollable anymore

Comment: @cmerriman the same. I need display:block, otherwise it is not scrollable. Sorry my mistake

Comment: According to James answer, it stays scrollable. Even if omit your `table` styles from css, it would still work.

Comment: @AakashThakur No it is not. In my example there is a scrollbar right under the table http://jsfiddle.net/dqq5B/515/ in your example the table does not have a scrollbar http://jsfiddle.net/dqq5B/520/ .What you mean is maybe the window scrollbar

Comment: But @Jarla the functionality that you want can simply be achieved with normal bootstrap table class and no further styling is needed for that. You won't get a scrollbar in case your table is big enough to accomodate its contents and in your case it is exactly the same. What you want is for the table to go full screen when the screen is wide enough. Now in such a wide screen having accomodable contents in the table, you shouldn't expect any scrollbar.

Comment: @Aakash Thakur Don't you see the scrollbar in my example, when you make your window small?

Comment: Ohh my bad. Now i got what you are trying to achieve exactly. You want scroll for the table and not the window.

Comment: @Aakash Thakur YEEES!! :D

Answer (score 2):

Just add 'display: table' to the table element in the CSS.

```
table {
    display:table
}
```

That'll work.
Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dqq5B/515/

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to obtain by adding all that css? 
If you are using the Bootstrap Framework, you just need to add the classes in your HTML.

Remove the extra CSS.

Comment: Exactly. I don't understand what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: When I remove the css, the table is not scrollable on smaller windows

Comment: @AakashThakur My table has its own scrolling bar on smaller devices.

Comment: in the above example you did not close the <div> tag at the end.

Comment: But bootstrap will automatically insert the scroll on smaller windows in case your table grows in width.

Comment: and inside your <style> tag you should not have any HTML. JUST CSS

Comment: @AakashThakur is right. Bootstrap will make the table scroll-able only if it exceeds the width of its parent

Comment: There is no scrollbar for the table: http://jsfiddle.net/dqq5B/522/ Only a scrollbar for the whole window